# Fixing bad topology during Sculpting

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, sculpt, dynamic-topology

Sometimes when I am sculpting with Dyntopo, the mesh topology will become terrible and it becomes difficult to fix. I have found a few ways to fix it, such as using the inflate and simplify brushes to expand and then simplify the mesh but it does not always work. Is there a better way to fix it? Also, how should I prevent it in the first place. I am using Dyntopo with constant detail (quite low, 10-12 resolution etc) and this usually happens when I use the clay strips on a thin mesh.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using Brush Detail instead of Constant detail, and try using Subdivide instead of Subdivide/Collapse. Tends to make nice clay-like strokes. You can still get kinks like the ones you show above, though. So keep using your Inflate + Simplify trick. That's a good trick. I use a similar trick where I go between Smooth and Simplify. But I like your version better. So I'm adopting it.